# non-unique index vs full table scan

Tags: sql-server, indexing

When a column is non-clustered index column, its key-row address relationship is stored somewhere else.

I understand if the index column data type is numeric, SQL server is using B-tree searching mechanism to find the answer.
How about when the column type is text, especially there can have duplicated values in the index?

What is the difference between SQL searches a separate table with key-row address pair and non-index column of the table?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that SQL Server would use a B-tree for text columns as well.  I also expect that an index could contain duplicates, in certain scenarios.

Comment: For example a indexed column is price with values of 1,3,6,8,10 in asc order. If we are looking for price=6 with index in B-tree SQL server can quickly find 6 before hit the end and stop there because 8 is bigger than 6 so SQL server will stop searching. But how about column as first name with values of 'Bill', ' Kelvin', 'Scott','Bill','Scott' ? How can SQL server quickly finds the answer that value = 'Bill'?

Comment: A B-tree with text works much like a phone book.  First you lookup the first letter, then find the second letter, etc., until finding the full name.  The full name in a phone book corresponds to the leaf node in a B-tree.

Comment: Thanks Tim. In this case, the SQL will search the full table then because the non-unique index means the value could potentially show up in the column more than one time? In other words, there is no benefit to index a non-unique column?

Comment: Read the answer by @David given below.

Answer (score 1):

> How about when the column type is text, especially there can have duplicated values in the index?

There is no difference in how nonclustered indexes on varchar/nvarchar values are handled.  Although the maximum key size is 1700 bytes.

And for duplicate values, all BTree indexes are actually stored as unique indexes.  If the index is non-unique, the clustered index key is added to each key value on the non-leaf pages. See [Geek City: More About Nonclustered Index Keys](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx)

> What is the difference between SQL searches a separate table with key-row address pair and non-index column of the table?

Very little.  If you look at the query plans you'll see what is essentially a join between the non-clustered index and the clustered index, the same as would be between a separate table and a clustered index.

Comment: So can I say it is meaningless to index a non-unique column because the database ends up with full table scan anyway?

Comment: No, that doesn’t follow at all.

Comment: One of the articles mentioned: the server will know that using an index will only reduce the results by 50%, and it may decide that it's not worth the bother and just do a table scan. What kind of benchmark here that SQL server will choose to ignore the index?